# What elements does this set have

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, analysis, matrices

What elements does the set $T_{2,3}$ in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200102/fea-knutson.pdf) exactly have? and how about $T_{3,3}$, and $T_{3,4}$?

Comment: can you give page no and paragraph so it will easy to find

Comment: @ iostream007: Page 176, Paragraph 1 to 3. Thanks.

Comment: It says there that Horn computed the sets you're asking about, and it [gives a reference](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1103036720).  Have you checked that reference?

Answer (score 2):

By *definition* the set $T_{r,n}$ is a set of all inequalities (or more precisely the index tuples describing the inequality) of type $(3)$ so that all conditions in $\bigcup_{1\le r\le n}T_{r,n}$ together with $(1)$ solve the problem at hand.

Apparently Horn has computed these sets *explcitly* for $n\le 8$.

By *conjecture* the sets are generally given by the Horn conjecture.